# Number of students and how many are taking X class (Discrete Structures)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So I have my first quiz tomorrow and want to get off on the good foot, but I'm studying some problems and this one is particularly confusing...

> There are a group of 191 students, of which 10 are taking French,
> business and music; 36 are taking French and business; 20 are taking
> French and music; 18 are taking business and music; 65 are taking
> French; 76 are taking business; and 63 are taking music.
>
> 1a. How many are taking French or business (or both)?
>  1b. How many are
> taking music or French (or both) but not business?

It might just be all the numbers confusing me, but I'm kind of lost.  For 1a: the answer I got was 177 but I don't think that can be right, as there are 63 taking music, which would push the total over 191...

I haven't even gotten through 1b, and I don't want to look at the answer just yet, as I'm trying to work my way through it.  Could anyone provide a bit of help?

Comment: Draw a venn diagram

Comment: I don't think you were correct, please look at my answer for clarification. The number of music students doesn't affect the value in 1a.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical Principle of Inclusion Exclusion principle problem.  This principle allows one to count various unions and intersections when there are multiple not necessarily disjoint sets in a problem.

The most simple example is in the case of two sets; let A denote the set of positive multiples of 3 under 1000 (so 3,6,9,...,999), and let B denote the set of positive multiples of 5 under 1000 (so 5,10,15...,995).  Then if |S| denotes the number of elements in a set S, the principle of inclusion and exclusion for A and B says:

$$
|A| + |B| - |A \cap B| = |A \cup B|
$$

There, $|A \cap B|$ represents the multiples of 5 and 3 (so multiples of 15), while $|A \cup B|$ represents the multiples of 5 OR 3.  Understand the distinction.

In the case of three sets, as in your problem (F for students in French, B for students in business, and M for students in music), the principle says:

$$
|F| + |B| + |M| - |F \cap B| - |F \cap M| - |B \cap M| + |F \cap B \cap M| = |F \cup B \cup M|
$$

In the equation above, $F \cup B$ (for example) represents the students in both French and business, whereas $F \cup B \cup M$ represents the set of all students (so 191).  You can use this expression to solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can either draw a venn diagram (if you are more of a visual learner), or use the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion.

So we have three probable events $$A, B, C$$

And from the question we have that:

$$P(A \cap B \cap C) = 10 $$

In order to find the number of students taking **only** French, we can say that:

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$
$$= 65 + 76 - 36 = 105$$

Can you use this idea to find the answer in part 1 b.?

Comment: Wow, I wish I this concept was actually taught in this section (they teach us about associate/distributive algebra of sets, but not this particular principle, which I'm guessing comes later).  I drew a Venn Diagram and was absolutely lost - but this makes it so much easier!